# Using object that returning by method of disposable object after dispose

Tags: c#

Have a code like this:

```
using(var disposableObject = new MyClass()) 
{
    var something = disposableObject.GetSomething();
    return something; 
}
```

So, I return not disposableObject, but object that produces by disposableObject. Is it right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you do. However, depending on what `GetSomething()` does, your `something` object might be unusable. For example, if `something` has references to `disposableObject` and needs it to perform certain operations.

For example, this code

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    return streamReader;
}
```

will produce an unusable `streamReader`.